# Problema al generar listado desordenado (<ul>) con bootstrap desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, bootstrap-3, recursión

El problema que tengo es al generar el listado este me presenta 2 problemas:

**1. Subniveles:** A partir del segundo subnivel se ajusta a la  izquierda. La funcion que genera el listado es recursiva y crea subniveles dependiendo del `json` (una consulta que hago de una tabla y esta tiene los subniveles que el usuario desee indicar (indeterminados)). Yo quisiera que el bootstrap los ordene indefinidamente.
**Nota:** la `funcion ordenar()` redimensiona el `json` por subniveles.

**2. Json:** Al generar el listado mas de 1 vez con el evento del clic del boton, este me repite los subniveles, ¿Como podría solucionar eso?.

```js
var arrayjson = [{
  "id": 5,
  "nombre": "Electrica",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "nombre": "Mecanica",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 7,
  "nombre": "Sellos",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 8,
  "nombre": "Motores",
  "id_padre": 6,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 55,
  "nombre": "Piston",
  "id_padre": 8,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 60,
  "nombre": "Bobina",
  "id_padre": 8,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 60,
  "nombre": "Viela",
  "id_padre": 8,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 9,
  "nombre": "Filtro",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 13,
  "nombre": "Sensores",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 10,
  "nombre": "Filtro 0,22 U",
  "id_padre": 9,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 11,
  "nombre": "Filtro Aceite",
  "id_padre": 9,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 12,
  "nombre": "Filtro De Agua",
  "id_padre": 9,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 16,
  "nombre": "Termico",
  "id_padre": 5,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 15,
  "nombre": "Relé",
  "id_padre": 5,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 14,
  "nombre": "Contactores",
  "id_padre": 5,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 17,
  "nombre": "Croche",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 18,
  "nombre": "Ajustar",
  "id_padre": 17,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 19,
  "nombre": "Desajustar",
  "id_padre": 17,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 20,
  "nombre": "Picos",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 21,
  "nombre": "Sujeción",
  "id_padre": 20,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 23,
  "nombre": "Formacion",
  "id_padre": 20,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 22,
  "nombre": "Altura",
  "id_padre": 20,
  "status": true
}];

function ordenar(j) {
 array = [];

 for (n in j) {
  insertar(j[n], 0, array);
 }
 return array;
}

function insertar(j, l, array) {
 for (n in array) {
  if (array[n].id == j.id_padre) {
   if (array[n].array == undefined)
    array[n].array = [];
   return array[n].array.push(j);
  } else {
   if (array[n].array)
    if (insertar(j, l+1, array[n].array))
     return true;
  }
 }
 if (l)
  return false;

 array.push(j);
}


function listado(array, l) {
 if ( l == undefined)
  l=0, html="";
 
 for (n in array) {
  html += "<div class='list-group'>\n";
        html += "<a href='#' class='list-group-item' data-id='"+array[n].id+"' data-padre='"+array[n].id_padre+"' data-status='"+array[n].status+"'><span class='fa fa-angle-right'></span> "+array[n].nombre+"</a>\n";
  if (array[n].array) {
   listado(array[n].array, l+1);
  };
  html += "</div>\n";
 };

return html;
}


$(document).on('click', '#GuardarParte', function() {
  document.getElementById("listado").innerHTML='';
  html=listado(ordenar(arrayjson));
  document.getElementById("listado").innerHTML=html;
});
```

```css
.just-padding {
  padding: 15px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button type="button" id="GuardarParte" name="GuardarParte" class="btn btn-primary">Generar</button> 

<div class="just-padding">
  <div class="list-group list-group-root well" id="listado">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado he vuelto local la variable `html` y he agregado al `html` local el creado por las llamadas recursivas.

Por otro lado, tu función ordenar modifica el array original, por lo que lo he llamado únicamente una vez antes de instaurar el evento `onclick`.

Con esas dos modificaciones tu código funciona correctamente.

```js
var arrayjson = [{
  "id": 5,
  "nombre": "Electrica",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 6,
  "nombre": "Mecanica",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 7,
  "nombre": "Sellos",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 8,
  "nombre": "Motores",
  "id_padre": 6,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 55,
  "nombre": "Piston",
  "id_padre": 8,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 60,
  "nombre": "Bobina",
  "id_padre": 8,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 60,
  "nombre": "Viela",
  "id_padre": 8,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 9,
  "nombre": "Filtro",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 13,
  "nombre": "Sensores",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 10,
  "nombre": "Filtro 0,22 U",
  "id_padre": 9,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 11,
  "nombre": "Filtro Aceite",
  "id_padre": 9,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 12,
  "nombre": "Filtro De Agua",
  "id_padre": 9,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 16,
  "nombre": "Termico",
  "id_padre": 5,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 15,
  "nombre": "Relé",
  "id_padre": 5,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 14,
  "nombre": "Contactores",
  "id_padre": 5,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 17,
  "nombre": "Croche",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 18,
  "nombre": "Ajustar",
  "id_padre": 17,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 19,
  "nombre": "Desajustar",
  "id_padre": 17,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 20,
  "nombre": "Picos",
  "id_padre": 0,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 21,
  "nombre": "Sujeción",
  "id_padre": 20,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 23,
  "nombre": "Formacion",
  "id_padre": 20,
  "status": true
},
{
  "id": 22,
  "nombre": "Altura",
  "id_padre": 20,
  "status": true
}];

function ordenar(padre) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (var n in arrayjson) {
    if (arrayjson[n].id_padre == padre) {
      var hijos = ordenar(arrayjson[n].id);
      if (hijos.length > 0) {
        arrayjson[n].array = hijos;
      }
      resultado.push(arrayjson[n])
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}

function listado(array, l) {
  var html='';
 
  for (n in array) {
    html += "<div class='list-group'>\n";
    html += "<a href='#' class='list-group-item' data-id='" + 
      array[n].id + "' data-padre='" + 
      array[n].id_padre + "' data-status='" + array[n].status +
      "'><span class='fa fa-angle-right'></span> " + array[n].nombre + "</a>\n";
    if (array[n].array) {
      html += listado(array[n].array, l + 1);
    }
    html += "</div>\n";
  }
  return html;
}

var ordenado = ordenar(0);

$(document).on('click', '#GuardarParte', function() {
  document.getElementById("listado").innerHTML = '';
  html = listado(ordenado);
  document.getElementById("listado").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```css
.just-padding {
  padding: 15px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root {
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root .list-group-item {
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group-item:first-child {
  border-top-width: 0;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.list-group.list-group-root > .list-group > .list-group > .list-group-item {
  padding-left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button type="button" id="GuardarParte" name="GuardarParte" class="btn btn-primary">Generar</button> 

<div class="just-padding">
  <div class="list-group list-group-root well" id="listado">
  </div>
</div>
```

PD: Ya que tienes jQuery a tu disposición, hay maneras mucho más sencillas de hacer tu trabajo y, sobre todo, sin ir agregando código HTML tan difícil de mantener.

Comment: Gracias, solo hay un problema, se repiten algunos subniveles, [cheka esta imagen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kbHA.png).

Comment: La función de `ordenar()` el `json` no la puedo sacar del botón, puesto que genero la lista de partes, a partir de una lista de equipos. Explico: tengo una lista de equipos, esta contiene la lista de partes, doy clic en cualquiera de los equipos y esta me generara la lista de partes, y la función ordenar la genero cada vez que escoja un equipo diferente.

Comment: Sí puedes sacarlo del evento del botón, no es necesario reordenar el array en cada evento, con una única vez y almacenar el resultado es suficiente, pero parece que esa función no hace bien su trabajo. Siento haberme centrado en resolver sólo la segunda parte, voy a mirar la primera parte de tu pregunta.

Comment: mmm pero cada equipo tiene partes diferentes.. y las partes son `json` diferentes. Si ejecuto la funcion ordenas con uno solo.

Comment: Estoy arreglando la función. Te recomiendo no usar bloques `if` sin llaves, aunque sólo tenga una única instrucción dentro. Y si decides hacerlo, mantén el código en la misma linea del `if`. Sigo depurando y arreglando el funcionamiento.

Comment: Lo siento, creo que guardé una edición intermedia que no funciona, dejé en casa el editor con el código a medias, estoy rehaciendo tu función pero es el día de la familia, hemos salido. Siento dejar esto parado durante unas tres o cuatro horas :(

Comment: ok, gracias. Fijate de este [`json`](https://api.myjson.com/bins/17xk7x) de como obtengo la data de los equipos. [Acá un ejemplo de mi lista de equipos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxRnf.png). Dentro de cada equipo tengo la data de las partes, la posicion 31 es la que contiene el array de partes.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58721/discussion-between-pablo-contreras-and-oscargarcia).

Comment: Parece que ahora va bien, echa un vistazo a mi edición, he simplificado tu función, espero que ahora haga lo que deseas. Por cierto, ¿has probado a hacerlo con jQuery o creando elementos en el DOM en vez de montar HTML de esa manera?